# Multiple bindings in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, racket

So, the Racket (6.5) documentation says you can bind several ids at once:

```
(for ([(i j) #hash(("a" . 1) ("b" . 20))])
    (display (list i j)))
```

Bu-u-ut I can't figure out / find an example of how to do this with manually constructed data:

```
(define a '(1 2 3 4 5))
(define b '(10 20 30 40 50))
(for ([(i j) (map list a b)])
    (display (list i j)))
```

explodes with

```
result arity mismatch;
 expected number of values not received
  expected: 2
  received: 1
  from: 
  in: local-binding form
  values...:
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
(for ([(i j) #hash(("a" . 1) ("b" . 20))])
    (display (list i j)))
```

is short for

```
(for ([(i j) (in-hash #hash(("a" . 1) ("b" . 20)))])
    (display (list i j)))
```

Now `in-hash` returns two values at a time, so `(i j)`
will be bound to the two values.

On the other hand, this:

```
(for ([(i j) (map list a b)])
    (display (list i j)))
```

is short for

```
(for ([(i j) (in-list (map list a b))])
    (display (list i j)))
```

and `in-list` will return one element at a time (in you example
the element is a list). Since there are two names in `(i j)`
and not just one, an error is signaled.

Follow Toxaris' advice in `in-parallel`.

UPDATE

The following helper `make-values-sequence` shows
how to create a custom sequence, that repeatedly
produces more than one value.

```
#lang racket

(define (make-values-sequence xss)
  ; xss is a list of (list x ...)
  (make-do-sequence (λ ()
                      (values (λ (xss) (apply values (first xss))) ;  pos->element
                              rest                                 ;  next-position
                              xss                                  ;  initial pos
                              (λ (xss) (not (empty? xss)))         ;  continue-with-pos?
                              #f                                   ;  not used
                              #f))))                               ;  not used]


(for/list ([(i j) (make-values-sequence '((1 2) (4 5) (5 6)))])
  (+ i j))
```

Output:

```
'(3 9 11)
```

Comment: Is there any particular way to directly write the compatible "sequence-of-two-values-at-a-time" (in the `(list (list 1 2) ...)` fashion) rather than `in-parallel`'s "rearrange these two single-value sequences and give me an opaque `#<sequence>`"?

Answer (score 6):

In this example, you can use separate clauses to bind  `i` and `j`:

```
(for ([i (list 1 2 3 4 5)]
      [j (list 10 20 30 40 50)])
  (display (list i j)))
```

More generally, you can use `in-parallel` to create a single sequence of multiple values from multiple sequences of single values:

```
(for ([(i j) (in-parallel (list 1 2 3 4 5)
                          (list 10 20 30 40 50))])
    (display (list i j)))
```

Both solutions print `(1 10)(2 20)(3 30)(4 40)(5 50)`.